# Bootstrap modal shows same content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching the answer for this question for two days and every code that I tried didn't work for me. All I'm trying to do is dynamically append pictures into the modal when a certain picture is clicked, but the same set of pictures show every time the modal opens. I believe the idea is to clear the modal body once the modal closes but I can't figure out how to do that and every example that I saw didn't work. This is the code I have.

```
var maxAppend = 0;

$(window).on("load",function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
    $("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    //$(".details-box").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var img2 = document.getElementById("myImg2");

var modalImg = ['./pictures/loginScreen.png',
                './pictures/pDisplay.png',
                './pictures/packageDetails.png',
                './pictures/financeOpt.png',
                './pictures/result.png']

var modalImg2 = ['./pictures/mOasis1.png',
                './pictures/mOasis2.png',
                './pictures/mOasis3.png',
                './pictures/mOasis4.png',
                './pictures/mOasis5.png']

var imgModal = document.getElementsByClassName("img01");

img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(maxAppend < 5){
        $(imgModal).append('<img src="'+modalImg[i]+'" class="img-fluid" alt="Login Screen" style="width:100%;max-width:700px;margin:10px"/>');
      maxAppend++;
    }
  }
}
img2.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(maxAppend < 5){
      $(imgModal).append('<img src="'+modalImg2[i]+'" class="img-fluid img" alt="Login Screen" style="width:100%;max-width:700px;margin:10px"/>');
      maxAppend++;
     }
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Try use `$(imgModal).eq(i).append(` , because when you use `$(imgModal).append(` it appends the content to the entire collection of `imgModal `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
img.onclick = function(){
  $(".img01").html("")
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.forEach(img => {
    $(".img01").append(`<img src="${img}" class="img-fluid" alt="Login Screen" style="width:100%;max-width:700px;margin:10px"/>`)
  })
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are **almost always** bad answers. And no, this answer is no exception to that rule.